# how to add texture to the GLB file for the 3D Model using @viro-community/react-viro

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I tried the below code to add texture to the OBJ file it's working fine but it's not working with the GLB file so how to add texture to the GLB file for the 3D Model using @viro-community/react-viro.

> This is a 3D object

```
<Viro3DObject
            source={require("./object_car.glb")}
            position={[0, 1, 0]}
            scale={[0.3, 0.3, 0.3]}
            type="GLB"
            lightReceivingBitMask={3}
            shadowCastingBitMask={2}
            transformBehaviors={["billboardY"]}
            materials={data.texture}
            onClick={_toggleButtons}
            rotation={[50, 50, -10]}
          />
```

> This is texture

```
ViroMaterials.createMaterials({
    white: {
       lightingModel: "PBR",
      diffuseTexture: require("./object_car_main_Base_Color.png"),
    },
    blue: {
      lightingModel: "PBR",
      diffuseTexture: require("./object_car_main_Base_Color_blue.png"),
    },
  });
```

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: No, I still have not found any solution, I can add texture to the .obj file but am not able to add texture to the .glb file

Comment: Same thing here, I ended up using the obj file.